# Automatically Session breakout in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I set my session in web.config file to 60 minutes but session automatically timeout even after 5 to 15 minutes.This is my webconfig file code in system.web

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60"/>
   </authentication>
   <sessionState timeout="60" mode="InProc" cookieless="false"/>
   <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
</system.web>
```

How I can I maintain the session state contatn so that my session will not expire before 60 minutes.

Comment: How do you know that the session has timed out? On what kind of web server you are hosting the site? Is a load balancer involved?

Comment: When I am updating any product and spend there 10 minutes in updating and when i Save it it will automatically redirect to me login page. Yes there is load balancer in server.

Comment: Then, is it possible that "Session afinity" or "sticky sessions" as sometimes called is not configured on the load balancer? Since your session state mode is inProc, both the session cookie and forms authentication cookie will be invalid if the load balancer sends the client request to a different server after 10 minutes. In one of the cases we experienced, session afinity was enabled on the load balancer but with an expiration of 5 minutes. That caused clients, spending more than 5 minutes on a page, to be redirected to the login page, randomly.

Comment: You can have session state mode state server or sql server to overcome this. There is also a way to share the forms authentication cookie between servers. [Here is the documentation]: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The session usually falls every 20 minutes after inactivity of the application.
One solution is to create a page that does nothing and send a request to that page every 10 minutes. In this way the session variables will be kept alive.

http://www.tenpay.tech/questions/1485532/keeping-session-alive-c-sharp

Comment: can you explain me? how it works and what happened if my page remain inactive till 60 minutes. also it will send request every 10 minutes but i don't want to send any request to server again and again.